# Is there a faster method to find the difference of each pixel neighbor in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm kinda new to image processing and I'm having trouble with the speed.
What I'm trying to do is "the difference between pixel values and the neighbors of them are calculated to discover whether there is a great contrast (>100 for this case) between them and accumulated"
[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvMyr.png)

It is working but it is very slow. Is there any optimal way to do this?

```
%%cython -a
import cython
import numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef unsigned char[:, :] test(unsigned char [:, :] image):
    w = image.shape[1]
    h = image.shape[0];
    Hi = [None] * w
    Vj = [None] * h
    
    #For Hi
    for y in range(0, w):
        value1 = 0
        for x in range(1, h):
            value = abs(image[x, y]- image[(x-1), y])
            if(value > 100):
                    value1+= value
        Hi[y]= value1
```

Comment: you could create a subimage which is shifted by 1 pixel and afterwards compute the absdiff between the original and the shifted image

Comment: Look at `numpy.diff` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

Comment: you could use `cv.filter2d` with a kernel of `[1,-1]`.